# Query on immigration - New Zealand

Tags: resident-permit, new-zealand

This is the principal applicant, applied for "Skilled migrant category - Expression Of Interest - New Zealand" with spouse(non-skilled), where application has been  selected from the pool.

My question:
With this Immigration process, Family migrating to New Zealand in first trip, Can spouse be back to home country for any medical or casual reasons until principal applicant gets settled with a job?

Comment: @mkennedy This is an important query for me, can you help me?

Comment: Are you asking whether, after grant of the immigrant visa, the spouse can travel back to his/her home country? If so, the answer is yes.